# <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> isn't work

Tags: css

It's in a folder called "Website" My css file has

```
body {
   background-color: #d0e4fe;
}
h1 {
   color: orange;
   text-align: center;
}
p {
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
   font-size: 22px;
}
```

WHY ISN'T IT WORKING?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong quotes. Instead of **“** quotes, try **"**

With a stylesheet named **style.css** placed at the same level than the web page, the following line works for me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Nope still nothing Should I specify like that the folder is Desktop? Btw i'm on Linux? If that matters

Comment: It's using relative path, meaning you do not have to specify anything else except if the web page and the css are in different folders. 

Also, could you download this and tell me if it works? It's basically your example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1nbvoqid0itzwxc/Example.zip

Comment: Didn't work for me. Everything was to the left when you centered it?

Comment: I took your CSS, so "Header" should be centered and the rest left-aligned. What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome and header? Do you mean the <Head>?

Comment: On the web page I sent you, I wrote three things: "Header" in a <h1> tag, "Paragraph" in a <p> tag and "Regular content" in the body. Can you see that?

Comment: Oh yes I just can't see it center aligned

Comment: Do you see the color in the background?

Comment: Nope Do you have skype?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href=“Website/style.css”>
```

Comment: please check the path of ur css file