# I can't import css file using 'static' template in django

Tags: css, python-3.x, django, web-applications, django-templates

I'm trying to develop my first web application using Django, so the site looks like that:

[Site without changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjhl6.png)

On the other hand, I would like to apply some changes and put it in a CSS file called: cabecalho.css

cabecalho.css file (with the changes) - path: (project/static/css/cabecalho.css):

```
     <style>
       body {
        font-family: Segoe UI;
       }
       .logo {
        float: left;
       }
       .logo img {
        width: 250px;
        padding: 20px;
       }
       .menu {
        float: right;
        padding: 40px;
        font-size: 15pt;
       }
       .menu a {
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
       }
       .bemvindo {
        clear: both;
        padding: 0 20px;
       }

       </style>
```

These changes make the site look like that:

[Site with CSS changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gt6F.png)

In my HTML file called cabecalho.html, I tried to import with the line code:

```
1 try: <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'css/cabecalho.css' %}/>

2 try: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/cabecalho.css" %}/>

3 try: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cabecalho.css">
```

In this way, nothing happens!

HTML file (cabecalho.html) - path: (project/templates/django/cabecalho.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %} <!-- Nova linha que carrega os arquivos estáticos -->

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Django Form Exemplo</title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'css/cabecalho.css' %}/>
    </head>

    <body>
     <div class='logo'>
       <img src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}" alt="Logo da Hacked" />
     </div>

     <div class='menu'>
       <a href="/app/sobre/">Sobre</a>
       <a href="/app/sair/">Sair</a>
     </div>

     <div class='bemvindo'>
       <h2>Bem vindo ao nosso Site Django Exemplo!</h2>
     </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Obs: If I drop this line and add the CSS content like below, the changes happen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %} <!-- Nova linha que carrega os arquivos estáticos -->

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Django Form Exemplo</title>
                          <style>
               body {
                font-family: Segoe UI;
               }
               .logo {
                float: left;
               }
               .logo img {
                width: 250px;
                padding: 20px;
               }
               .menu {
                float: right;
                padding: 40px;
                font-size: 15pt;
               }
               .menu a {
                margin-left: 15px;
                margin-right: 15px;
               }
               .bemvindo {
                clear: both;
                padding: 0 20px;
               }

               </style>

    </head>

    <body>
     <div class='logo'>
       <img src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}" alt="Logo da Hacked" />
     </div>

     <div class='menu'>
       <a href="/app/sobre/">Sobre</a>
       <a href="/app/sair/">Sair</a>
     </div>

     <div class='bemvindo'>
       <h2>Bem vindo ao nosso Site Django Exemplo!</h2>
     </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Questions that I've ever tried:

[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> isn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824383/link-rel-stylesheet-type-text-css-href-style-css-isnt-work)

[import css using 'static' template in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824544/import-css-using-static-template-in-django)

More information:

views.py (app/views.py):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):


    
    return render(request, 'django/cabecalho.html')
```

settings.py (project/settings.py):

```
"""
Django settings for project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#w1odqj&ebl80i3)@m=y5uq@q+rf!+7bk6!&qt@0h8b1#xfy8g'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('C:/Users/Leonardo/microblog/project/templates',)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')  # concatena a pasta static a variavel instanciada base_dir que aponta para a raiz do projeto

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # chamada que terá no browswer para a pasta de arquivos estaticos

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

Folders:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXuQJ.png)

Comment: How are you serving your application?

Comment: Daniel, I write a CSS code with some settings to be imported into the HTML file. Then I have a view with the code: def index(request):  return render(request, 'django/cabecalho.html')

Answer (score 0):

you are forgetting the outer dubble quotes of href attribute `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/cabecalho.css' %}"/>`

Comment: in your browser console any error is showing related to cabecalho.css